# How to delete a unit of measurement from the Units dialog?

Tags: gimp, measurement, units

In GIMP 2.10.6 there's a `Units` dialog (`Edit > Units`) where you can add your own units of measurement, but there is no obvious way to remove them. How can you remove custom made units of measurement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just untick the check mark in the `Saved` column (you cannot "unsave" the first four):

[image]

Comment: Ok so I missed that because I didn't read the headings + it only removes them after restarting GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

The units are stored in the `unitrc` file. For Windows users this is located in the `AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10` directory. Here you can manually edit the unit entries.